# Why does my web service not receive any data from my HTML form?

Tags: php, html, database, web-services, post

I have a HTML form that (should) send the user input data to a web PHP service:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register Form</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="localhost/test.php" method="POST">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Thema :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="theme" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Jahr :</td>
    <td><input type="number" name="year" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Speichern"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The web service will enter the data into a MySQL Database. This works fine. I know that, because if I open the web service in my browser it fill a row in my database with *NULL*. But if I click the submit button on my HTML site it neither fill the user input nor *NULL*. Here's my web service:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['theme']) && isset($_POST['year'])) {
        
        $theme = $_POST['theme'];
        $year = $_POST['year'];}
        $url = "127.0.0.1";
        $database = "songs";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        
        $connect = mysqli_connect($url, $username, $password, $database);   
            
                    if(!$connect) 
                    {
                        die("Connection failed: ".$connect->connect_error);
                    }
            
                    //create a template
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO theme (theme, year) VALUES (?, ?);";
          
            
                    //create a prepared statement
                    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
            
            
                    //prepare the prepared statement
                    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                        echo "SQL statement failed";
                    } else {
                        //bind parameters to the placeholders
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $theme, $year);      //1 string, 1 integer, is equal to theme and year
                        //run parameters inside database
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                        mysqli_close($connect);
                    }
?>
```

I know that my HTML site is working, because on [webhook.site](https://webhook.site) it shows me the input. (Please ignore missing error handling and everything on my web service, I know that.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to `var_dump($_POST)` yet to verify your script actually receives the data?

Comment: You can not post data in web service. you have use CURL function for your requirement.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ - for starters, you failed to give an accurate problem description. What response/output are you getting from your script - none? Or one of your custom error messages?

Comment: Assuming this goes into the outermost IF here to begin with, then I’d expect that you most likely would get `SQL statement failed` … because your query contains an unquoted reserved word used as a column name.

Comment: @CBroe Bro calm down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form tag , the value of action should be test.php if both html and the file are in same folder. Otherwise put the relative path. Not localhost/test.php.

Comment: Thank you so much, its working now! Mistakes this simple can be such a headache..